# preg_replace expression and wrapping expression

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace, bbcode

So I've put together this BB code thing that will convert certain tags to html tags later on. It all works great, except when it comes to a h tag and align=center/left/right/justify tag (which translates to `<h1>` and `<p style="text-align=center/left/right/justify"`). It would seem like it interferes with the script due to the number 1 (number 1 is refering to the text). How would I go about to solve this problem? I'd like to keep h1 and such, but it would be wonderful if you could center align it yet keep it big  text.

```
function parseBBCode($sound_edit_long_desc){
$original = array(
'/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/',
'/\[h\](.*?)\[\/h\]/',
'/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/',
'/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/',
'/\[s\](.*?)\[\/s\]/',
'/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/',
'/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/',
'/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/',
'/\[align=left\](.*?)\[\/align\]/',
'/\[align=right\](.*?)\[\/align\]/',
'/\[align=center\](.*?)\[\/align\]/',
'/\[align=justify\](.*?)\[\/align\]/'
);
$replace = array(
'<strong>\\1</strong>',
'<h1>\\1</h1>',
'<em>\\1</em>',
'<u>\\1</u>',
'<strike>\\1</strike>',
'<img src="\\1">',
'<a href="\\1" class="alink" target="_blank">\\2</a>',
'<code>\\1</code>',
'<p class="post" style="text-align: left;">\\1</p>',
'<p class="post" style="text-align: right;">\\1</p>',
'<p class="post" style="text-align: center;">\\1</p>',
'<p class="post" style="text-align: justify;">\\1</p>'
);
$new = preg_replace($original, $replace, $sound_edit_long_desc);
 return nl2br($new);
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of `$sound_edit_long_desc` for testing with the `parseBBCode` function?

Comment: @Kstro21 [align=center][h]test text[/h][/align]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works ok, you can explore the final source code, for example in `Firefox` and `Chrome` press `Ctr`+`U` and you will see that there is a `h1` inside a `p` tag.

Your problem is that the final html is **syntactically incorrect** and may result in a browser error. You cannot have a `h1` inside a `p` element. You can read a lot about in the web.

Search google for `h1 inside p tag`

Consult the w3.org docs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html)

Read this [Will enclosing an `<h1>` element inside a `<p>` element affect SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49445/will-enclosing-an-h1-element-inside-a-p-element-affect-seo)

Hope it help